# Tipos anulables en Java equivalentes a los de C#, ¿Posible?

Tags: java, c#, tipos

El propósito principal de esta pregunta es aportar contenido a Stack Overflow en español

En C# podemos convertir tipos de datos (que no aceptan el valor null) en anulables; asignar null a este tipo de datos, produce un error de sintaxis ya que C# realiza la verificación mientras se escribe.

Es decir, que si tuvieramos algo como `float flotante = null;` generaría el error: `float es un tipo que no acepta valores null`

Aunque si se coloca el signo de pregunta delante del tipo, entonces e convierte en anulable y admite valores null.

Sería algo como:

```
bool? booleano = null;
int? entero = null;
float? flotante = null;
decimal? decim = null;
```

Ahora bien, hay algún equivalente en Java?

Comment: En realidad, para aclarar, el ? es sugar sintaxis. Los tipos nullables no existen en C# tampoco, si no que hay un struct Nullable<T> la cual puede hacer que cualquier tipo primitivo sea anulable. Los primitivos siguen sin ser nulables, solo que hay una struct que les permite serlo.

Comment: Referencia al source de C# al respecto: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

En Java no se aceptan valores null en tipos de datos primitivos, pero sí en los objetos. Por lo que si por ejemplo quiere asignar null a un booleano, no podrá `boolean boleano = null;`

En cambio, puede usar por ejemplo la clase `Boolean encuadrada` (el objeto `java.lang.Boolean` que es una clase/objeto ordinaria/o en lugar de un tipo primitivo).

Puedes usar:

```
Boolean b = null;
```

Y luego también establecer verdadero o falso por una simple asignación:

```
Boolean b = true; o Boolean b = false;
```

Esto se llama [Primitive wrapper class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class) o clase de envoltura primaria, que son clases a las que se les puede asignar valores de tipos primarios, pero que al ser objetos, también aceptan null;

A continuación te dejo algunos tipos de estas clases:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva a tí, y también a futuros lectores. Suerte.

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto, Java no admite la conversión implícita a `Nullable` de tipos primarios como C#, pero si se puede aplicar sobre objetos que cumplen funciones similares de manejo de tipos primarios.

Objetos como `Integer`, `Character`, o `Boolean`, `Float`, `Long`, `Short` manejan dichos valores conservando su tipo objeto que a su vez admite valor null.

Answer (score -1):

No, no existe el mismo concepto en Java. Lo mas similar a los tipos nullables de C# es la clase `java.util.Optional<T>`